# How .any() fetching rows instead of columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe df, where I have some NaN values in some columns.
I am trying to identify the rows by below code:

```
fb_df[fb_df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
```

**It is working perfectly fine but my doubt is that axis=1 is passed in any(); then how the code is checking in rows when as per my understanding it should check columns.**

Please help!!

Comment: By mistake the dataframe name is fb_df  not df  :(

Comment: The axis parameter specifies how you want to check. The default for most (all?) functions is `axis=0` which you can think of as column-wise. Specifying `axis=1` means that it performs the operation row-wise

Comment: Is it some kind of bug !!  because even when I am running this

fb_df[fb_df.isnull().any(axis='columns')]

I am getting same row wise operation  :(

Comment: when we drop columns we use axis =1 because that is a column-wise operation. It is contradicting :(

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Post some sample data please.